# How to fix "Access to image [Image Url] from origin http:localhost:3000 has been blocked by CORS Policy (React & HTML Canvas)

Tags: reactjs, canvas

I have a code that takes a image url and draws it on the canvas however i get faced with this error and my image does not appear on the canvas , the canvas stays empty.

**ERROR**

```
Access to image at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/object-cut-images/54062ac7-59dd-4684-baf4-840e6c5a2c3c.png' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Below IS My Code for drawing the image on the canvas

```
const Testing = () => {

  const canvasRef = useRef(null)
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current
    canvas.width = 100
    canvas.height = 100

    const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    const image = new Image()
    image.src= "https://storage.googleapis.com/object-cut-images/54062ac7-59dd-4684-baf4-840e6c5a2c3c.png"
    image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    image.onload = () => {
      context.drawImage(image , 0 , 0 , canvas.width , canvas.height)
      console.log(context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width , canvas.height).data.length)
    }
     
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <canvas className={styles.canvasCont} ref={canvasRef}>

      </canvas>
    </>
  )
}
```

As can be seen in the code I have even added "image.crossOrigin" to be anonymous so why is it not functioning properly? Am I missing something?

Comment: _"As can be seen in the code I have even added "image.crossOrigin" to be anonymous so why is it not functioning properly?"_ - because that doesn't do what you think it would. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-crossorigin

Comment: I am a bit lost, I am a beginner at this, what solution would you suggest to make it work? Is there any other way to make the image appear on the canvas ? @CBroe

Comment: You either need to load it from a CORS-enabled system (don't know if Google storage lets you configure this), or you will need to load the image via a _CORS proxy_ on your server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find the solution to this by simply setting up a proxy in my package.JSON file like so:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3000"
```

And removed the "image.crossOrigin" and it works perfectly now!

According to the error, it said "origin 'http://localhost:3000'" and that is why you see the proxy is "http://localhost:3000".